<UL> list inside <nav> where UL is given position: absolute and<nav> is given position: relative rendered in a dialog, Can't scroll to end of dialog
<UL> list inside <nav> where UL is given position: absolute and is given position: relative rendered in a dialog, Can't scroll to end of dialog..when nav is opened
<nav>
    <button
        (click)="toggleMenu()"
    >
        <span> "button" </span>

    </button>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        
    </ul>
</nav>

this is a dropdown menu I created And added css
 nav
 position: relative
 ul
 position: absolute

Now when the dropdown menu is used in a dialog the ul list is
dynamic the dialog isn't calculating the height of the ul list,
(scroll is seen on dialog but part of it is cut )
so some part of ul list is not seen..as it can't be scrolled more
than that
should scroll to end of dialog

Share your code. Assumption is hard here. How one can help you without seeing what did you actually code?

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I've edited your question to make the code you included visible, but it's too minimal to reproduce the problem.  It would be helpful if you included a code snippet that actually demonstrates the issue.  (Edit the question and use the button labeled <> to add a snippet)
